# How to show strong operator continuity for zero implies in ball

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\eta: M \mapsto B(\mathcal{K})$ is strong operator continuous at zero, we are putting vN algebra $M$ with Strong operator topology and $B(\mathcal{K})$ Weak operator topology, how to say $\eta$ is continuous on $(M)_2$, the ball of radius 2??

Comment: What the hell are you talking about?  S.O.T? W.O.T?  Well, no hard feelings of course but I find this one quite cryptic.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I guess S.O.T = strong operator topology, right?  Still, it's pretty cryptic . . .

Comment: The thing is, you want folks to ***work*** on answering your post, not deciohering it!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis: anyone who knows what a von Neumann algebra is, knows what sot and wot mean. It is standard in many, many, many papers in the subject, and in many books. Actually, papers and books are "cryptic" when they don't use wot and sot, because they use "weak" and "strong", which are less specific.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  OK, fair enough.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit harsh. Over the years I have seen many downvotes and close votes on specialized questions (like von Neumann algebras) by people who have zero reputation on the subject, and it has made me a bit sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking: if $x_j\to x$, then $x_j-x\to0$ (and conversely). So if $\eta $ is continuous at zero and linear, 
$$
\lim_j\eta(x_j)=\lim_j \eta(x_j-x)+\eta(x)=\eta(x). 
$$
That continuity at zero implies continuity everywhere holds for any linear topology and any linear function (with the above argument).

Comment: But we already showed for weak operator continuous linear functional continuity at zero does not imply continuous at every point.

Comment: Who's "we"? Linear topology, linear function, continuity translates.

Comment: According to your logic , a linear functional w.o.t continuous on the unit ball of $M_1$ , then in particular it is continuous is zero, so this will imply according to your argument it will be continuous everywhere, then this will say $\sigma$-weak dual is same as w.o.t dual, which is not true.

Comment: No. You are confusing continuity at a point with continuity in a certain topological subspace. A function may be continuous at $0$ without being continuous on the unit ball.

Comment: Okk, something wrongly understood.